# How to have more visible options in a SELECT component when using floating labels and size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get a floating label to play nicely with an HTML select with `size="5"` using Bootstrap 5.3.x (the latest version) but I cannot make it work or simply it is not possible without some hacks or I am just missing something from Bootstrap docs.

As per docs for [Select](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/select/#sizing) I should be able to expand the element a little bit more but as I said I cannot.

This is an example HTML I have created for show the issue:

```
<div class="form-floating">
  <select id="example" name="example" size="5" class="form-select form-select-sm">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
  <label for="example">Works with selects</label>
</div>
```

and here is the result:

[image]

I have also created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/bcL9jzh1/) so you can play with it and see the issue I am having.

Can I get some ideas or help? I would like to have more options visible in the select but also use the floating label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported:

> ### Floating labels
>
> #### Selects
>
> **Selects with `size` and `multiple` are not supported.**
>
> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/floating-labels/#selects